# How to get Spring application startup time / duration in code

Tags: spring, spring-boot

When I start my Spring application, I can see the startup time in console (I am using IntelliJ IDEA).

For example, below log shows 13.427s startup time for the application.

```
2016-12-29 13:58:05.491     : Starting Application on 8DSXD72 with PID 14120 
2016-12-29 13:58:05.518     : Running with Spring Boot v1.4.1.RELEASE, Spring v4.3.3.RELEASE
2016-12-29 13:58:05.519     : The following profiles are active: LOCAL
2016-12-29 13:58:15.537     : JMX is disabled
....
2016-12-29 13:58:17.392     : Started Application in 13.427 seconds (JVM running for 14.71)
```

Is there a way to get this startup time in the code? I want to print out application startup time in Spring `/info` endpoint.

Comment: That specific timer is not available, no. You can get something _close_ by registering a `SpringApplicationRunListener` that starts a timer on `started` and stops it on `finished`, then somehow exposes it to your endpoint handler.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thanks. Your solution is better. Please post an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is based on Sotirios's comment.

First, create a custom class which implements `SpringApplicationRunListener`.

```
package com.example;

public class AppListener implements SpringApplicationRunListener {
    public static long appStartTime;
    public static long appFinishTime;

    //Constructor is required.
    public AppListener(SpringApplication application, String[] args) {
    }

    @Override
    public void started() {
        appStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    @Override
    public void environmentPrepared(ConfigurableEnvironment environment) {

    }

    @Override
    public void contextPrepared(ConfigurableApplicationContext context) {

    }

    @Override
    public void contextLoaded(ConfigurableApplicationContext context) {

    }

    @Override
    public void finished(ConfigurableApplicationContext context, Throwable exception) {
        appFinishTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
```

Then, add this line to `spring.factories` file.

```
org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListener=com.example.AppListener
```

Answer (score 3):

Using ApplicationReadyEvent is less intrusive and minimal change.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TrackSpringBootTimeApp {
    private static Instant startTime;
    private static Instant endTime;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        startTime = Instant.now();
        SpringApplication.run(TrackSpringBootTimeApp.class);
        System.out.println("Total time taken in start up " + 
        Duration.between(startTime, endTime).toString());
    }

    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void startApp() {
        endTime = Instant.now();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ConfigurationProperties
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch("App");
    stopWatch.start("App Startup");
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    stopWatch.stop();
    System.out.println("Seconds = "+stopWatch.getTotalTimeSeconds());
    System.out.println(stopWatch.prettyPrint());
}
....
```

You can get the application startup time using the Spring utility **StopWatch**(org.springframework.util.StopWatch)